# How to tell if all buttons in an array are not selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uibutton

I have an array of buttons:

```
pokemon_cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[pokemon_cards addObject:self.cardButton1];
[pokemon_cards addObject:self.cardButton2];
[pokemon_cards addObject:self.cardButton3];
```

later in some method I want to do a BOOL check to see if ALL of them are NOT selected simultaneously. In other words, if ALL of them are not selected notify user, otherwise proceed, even if just one of them is selected.

Here is what i've done but its not working and I can't figure out how to do this without adding the buttons in the loop to a temporary array:

```
-(BOOL)userCanProceedToTurn {
   for (UIButton *button in pokemon_cards) {
      if (![button isSelected]) {
        // This only works for OR condition I want it to work for &&
         return NO;
      } else {
         return YES;
      }
   }
}
```

So this is what I want it to do pretty much but the function above doesn't work for &&:

```
if (![self.cardButton1 isSelected] && ![self.cardButton2 isSelected] && ![self.cardButton3 isSelected]) {
   //notify users they must selected at least one card
} else {

}
```

But i don't know which cards will be added to the array, that depends on the user, so I don't know how to check for that in the for loop

EDIT

I have implemented the code as suggested below. and as mentioned before this does not the && check that I was concerned with.

For example i need to make sure ALL cards are not currently in the 'not selected' state. but if one of those 3 cards are then they can proceed, even if the other two aren't. but with the check below, it will not proceed because the else statement is in the loop as well so everytime the loop is ran the buttons that aren't selected cause it to not proceed because the loop is ran 3 times.

here is my complete bool method, everything else works fine except the button one:

```
-(BOOL)userCanProceedToTurn {

    if (self.energyAmount == 0) {
     UIAlertView *view .. tell users they need energy before proceeding
     return NO;
    }
    if (self.usernameLabel.text.length == 0) {
      //Tell user they are not signed in
      return NO;
    }
    NSLog(@"button is %lu", (unsigned long)pokemon_cards.count);
    for (UIButton *button in pokemon_cards) {
      if ([button isSelected]) {
        NSLog(@"button.tag == %lu",button.tag);
        return YES;
      } else {
           UIAlertView *view .. tell users they need to select at least one card
         //this gets called because the loop is ran as many times there are buttons so inevitably i'll get an error. Which is why this works for the first button only, because it stops looping after it found that one since it was the first once selected
         return NO;
      } 
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you actually need to know the state of each button?
Why not take the opposite approach:

```
- (BOOL)userCanProceedToTurn {
    for (UIButton *button in pokemon_cards) {
        if ([button isSelected]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

EDIT

As a rule of thumb, methods that return a `BOOL` value should start with a flag set to `YES` or `NO` and only invert that flag, never setting it back to its original value. So basically, start with with `BOOL result = YES` and only flip it to `NO`, never ever flip it back to `YES`. This will have the pseudo-security of preventing something bad to happen.

Here's your method rewritten with this concept:

```
- (BOOL)userCanProceedToTurn {
    BOOL isEverythingOK = NO;
    NSString *message = nil;

    if (self.energyAmount != 0) {
        isEverythingOK = YES;
    } else {
        message = @"You need energy before proceeding.";
    }

    if (self.usernameLabel.text.length != 0) {
        isEverythingOK = YES;
    } else {
        message = @"You are not signed in.";
    }

    for (UIButton *button in pokemon_cards) {
        if ([button isSelected]) {
            isEverythingOK = YES;
        } else {
            message = @"You need to select at least one card"
        }
    }

    if (!isEverythingOK) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWith use the message here]
    }
    return isEverythingOK
}
```

Comment: hmm this doesn't work. it only checks the first button, even if there are multiple in the array

Comment: Exactly, which is more efficient than continuing to loop over buttons if you already have your answer.

Comment: @JteveSobs This does what you asked - if any one button is selected, is says the user can proceed. In other words, if none are selected, don't proceed.

Comment: @rmaddy it's probably me. ha it's definetly easier on the eyes. i'll try to find what I did wrong, i logged pokemon_cards.count and it returned the correct amount but user cant proceed if any of the objects after the 0 index is selected.

Comment: @rmaddy see my edit. I think i explain it better why it isn't working but for the first button. I need to run more than one check before proceeding, like "if usernameLabel.text.length == 0" then don't proceed as well, so many checks in the bool method

Comment: zinger! much better @bensarz thanks. and i learned something today. I didn't know about the rule of thumb for bools. I'll start using that from now on so I feel smart :) thank you

Comment: I wonder why do the method have to check the buttons even the energy is zero. It is not "efficient".

Comment: @JasonNam you're right! Would be much easier if this was Swift... ┻━┻ ヘ╰( •̀ε•́ ╰)

Answer (score 1):

We can sum up the questions, answers and comments. You can use these methods to do what you want :)

```
- (BOOL)userCanProceedToTurn
{
    // Check Username

    if (self.usernameLabel.text.length == 0)
    {
        [self showMessage: @"You are not signed in."];
        return false;
    }

    // Check Energy

    if (!(energyAmount > 0))
    {
        [self showMessage: @"You need energy before proceeding."];
        return  false;
    }

    // Check Cards

    for (UIButton *button in pokemon_cards)
    {
        if ([button isSelected])
        {
            return true
        }
    }

    [self showMessage: @"You need to select at least one card"];
    return false;
}

- (void)showMessage:(NSString *)title
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: title message: nil delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
}
```

If you need to know which buttons are selected then try

```
-(BOOL)userCanProceedToTurn
{
    NSMutableArray *pokemon_cards_temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (UIButton *button in pokemon_cards)
    {
        if ([button isSelected])
        {
            [pokemon_cards_temp addObject:button];
        }
    }

    // Do what you want with the selected buttons

    if ([pokemon_cards_temp count] > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) The `return` statements are backwards. 2) There's no point in checking them all. If any one is selected, return `YES` (like the other answer).

Comment: this is what I was trying to avoid @Jason per my comments in my question.  but i might resort to this if it's all that works

Comment: @JteveSobs Would you check my answers again? :)